# How to make pycharm's editor resolve the modules which are moved out of source root

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

My project is like the following:

```
.
├── addons
│   ├── module1
│   │   └── __init__.py
               def method1(self):
│   └── module2
│       └── __init__.py
└── src
    ├── addons
    │   ├── module3
    │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   └── module4
    │       └── __init__.py
    └── main.py
           from src.addons.module1 import method1
```

A method "method1" is defined in the /addons/module1, an importing method1 is called from the main.py. it executes the following command to run the code.

```
src/main.py --addons="./addons,./src/addons"
```

In pycharm, the directory "src" is marked as source root. PyCharm doesn't know how to resolve the method1 in the code "from src.addons.module1 import method1" in its code editor. It reports "unresolved reference 'method1'".

The outer "addons" can't be moved or mounted to the "src/addons" in the file system since the code is organized in a source code repository.

My question is how to change the PyCharm project to make it resolve the module1 successfully without changing the python code.

Comment: Have you considered using symlinks? I can't guarantee it'll work, but you can try symlinking your addons/module1 dir to src/addons/module1

Comment: Yes, I have considered using symlinks. It can't link the addons folder directly because it already has a folder named addons". It will not keep synchronizing new subfolders if I symlink all subfolders, so it also can't link subfolders.  I also considered mount using bind option. The git will found untracked folders because two groups of folders are merged.